# React Native Android TV Controls

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-tv

I'm currently trying to develop an Android TV application using React Native.
According to the React Native  documentation:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-for-apple-tv.html
(Navigate to the Android tab)

> "When running on Android TV the Android framework will automatically apply a directional navigation scheme based on relative position of focusable elements in your views"

However, I am running the app on the Android TV emulator but none of the keyboard controls nor the Directional pad controls in the emulator are making any changes.
I am able to navigate and change buttons in the Apple TV emulator using both the keyboard direction keys and the Apple TV remote control in the emulator.
Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: I don't know what the real problem is here but I suggest you to try sending key events from command line `adb shell input keyevent`. If that works you might narrow down the possible problems. 
Here’s an example:
`# KEYCODE_DPAD_UP
$ adb shell input keyevent 19`
See the (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) for the full list of available inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Great news to tell.

You can use the latest react native which is fully supporting Android TV now.

Check this out https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tags

For current time I use v0.55.0-rc.2